# Trying to understand System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6

I need to restrict access to all but one view in my `ASP.NET MVC4` project on our public site. We have to prevent a login screen from appears because AD is not setup on our public server as well.

From what I've read about `System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler`, the way I understand it is if I include the following line in my `web.config` all `cshtml` pages in my `/Views` folder will be restricted from view:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="*.cshtml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHander"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

However, when I play around with this setting in both of my web.config files, nothing is restricted from view on my local machine when I test. I have my program setup to run on my local IIS7 (our public site is IIS6). I feel I misunderstand how this works.

Comment: Do you want to block access to your website temporarily?

Answer (score 1):

**For IIS 6**

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="*.cshtml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

**For IIS 7**

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

To deep dive in this topic read [This Blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/06/25/aspnetmvc-block-view-access.aspx/)